# Required parameter on select tag isn't work

Tags: html, laravel, materialize

I am working on a stock system with Laravel 7.0 and Materializes Css and in a specific form I need to signal the fields that are required.I did this task without any problems with text input but not with select. The syntax seems correct to me but something is going wrong and I don't know what.

```
<form action="{{route('produto.cadastrar')}}" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <br>                                                                  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s1"></div>
        <div class="input-field col s4">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">plus_one</i>
            <input required type="number" placeholder="5" name="quantity">
            <label>Quantity <span class="important">*</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col s2"></div>
        <div class="input-field col s4">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">fitness_center</i>
            <select name="measure" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose the measure</option>
                @forelse($measure as $measure)
                <option value="{{$measure->measure}}">{{$measure->measure}}</option>
                @empty
                <option value="without measure">without measure</option>
                @endforelse
            </select>
            <label>measure<span class="important">*</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col s1"></div>
    </div>                                                                
    <div class="row valign center">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue darken-4"><b>Submit
                <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label ><span class="important">*</span> Required Field</label>
    </div>

    <br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

delete `value`  attr from your option tag

```
<option disabled selected>Choose the measure</option>
```

Comment: I did that and unfortunately nothing has changed, the selection signal has not yet been shown.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try again with this by changing this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue darken-4" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

If you add type="submit", the program will detect these required fields

Comment: What I want to do is show the sign that the field is empty. However, the way it is, for some reason, is not showing up, even with changes to this code that you submitted

Comment: @JuanGustavo i have fixed my answer. Please try again with this. If you add type="submit", the program will detect these required fields.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who tried to solve my question, your code is right but investigating better using the "inspect element" I found that in fact the error is because the materialize uses input text and listing (ul, li) to customize the select. The solution to this is in the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('select').formSelect();
 $("select[required]").css({display: "inline", height: 0, padding: 0, width: 0});
 });
</script>
```